# Neo4j 3.0.6 - TRIM Cypher Query on Windows and Linux

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My PC using `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]` but my server using `Linux 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 22:22:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I am using same query at my neo4j server

```
MATCH (n:Lah)
WHERE n.name = TRIM(' new  LAH  ')
RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

This is what I got from running on server using OS Linux :
[image]

And this is what I got from running on my PC, using OS Windows :
[image]

The question is, Why I got different result when I have same Query? Because I have Java Project that I develop from Windows and I build it on Linux Server.
What I need to do to make my query work?

**UPDATE**

After check on my co-worker PC, he has same OS with me, and running same Query, the result somehow is empty too. Any idea what is the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: In the query you pasted, there are two spaces in `new  LAH`. Is that intentional? Also, what happens if you simply run the query with `WHERE n.name = 'new  LAH'`?

Comment: Are you accessing the *same* neo4j DB server from the Windows and linux machines? For example, if you are always using the `localhost:7474` URL from all machines, then you are not using the same DB.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas If i use that, it will return all the nodes, but I need to use Trim for other reasons. I just showing the simple way to explain :)

Comment: @cybersam I downloaded from Server (Linux), and running on localhost:7474. It should be same database.

Comment: When you use `localhost` as the host address, you are accessing the DB server on the *same* (local) machine, not the server on another machine. So, your Windows machine is running a DB server that has the data you want. Your linux server does not have the same data.

Comment: @cybersam It has same data, i am pretty sure about that. Coz I download the database from my linux and i use it to run at my local.